# calculate score based on array object using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m beginner in JavaScript   and I’m trying to make a quiz that calculates the score of object(type) in the array. So the total score should count how much the user get in each part(ex:2/2 in math, 1/2 in science. Total= 3/4).
Is there any possible way to do that using jquery ?
help me please, thank you

```js
var all_questions = [{
  type:"math",
  question_string: "4 + 4",
  choices: {
    correct: "8",
    wrong: ["2", "3", "9"]
  }
}, {
  type:"math",
  question_string: "4 * 4",
  choices: {
    correct: "16",
    wrong: ["24", "13", "4"]
  }
}, {
  type:"sience",
  question_string: "What part of the body helps you move?",
  choices: {
    correct: "Muscles",
    wrong: ["Eyes", "Pancreas", "Lungs"]
  }
}, {
   type:"sience",
  question_string: 'What star shines in the day and provides light?',
  choices: {
    correct: "Sun",
    wrong: ["Moon", "Venus", "Mars"]
  }
}];
var Quiz = function(quiz_name) {
  this.quiz_name = quiz_name;
  this.questions = [];
}
Quiz.prototype.add_question = function(question) {
  var index_to_add_question = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.questions.length);
  this.questions.splice(index_to_add_question, 0, question);
}
Quiz.prototype.render = function(container) {
  var self = this;
  $('#quiz-results').hide();
  $('#quiz-name').text(this.quiz_name);
  var question_container = $('<div>').attr('id', 'question').insertAfter('#quiz-name');
  function change_question() {
    self.questions[current_question_index].render(question_container);
    $('#prev-question-button').prop('disabled', current_question_index === 0);
    $('#next-question-button').prop('disabled', current_question_index === self.questions.length - 1);
    var all_questions_answered = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.questions.length; i++) {
      if (self.questions[i].user_choice_index === null) {
        all_questions_answered = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    $('#submit-button').prop('disabled', !all_questions_answered);
  }
  var current_question_index = 0;
  change_question();
  $('#prev-question-button').click(function() {
    if (current_question_index > 0) {
      current_question_index--;
      change_question();
    }
  });
 
  $('#next-question-button').click(function() {
    if (current_question_index < self.questions.length - 1) {
      current_question_index++;
      change_question();
    }
  });
  $('#submit-button').click(function() {
    var score = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.questions.length; i++) {
      if (self.questions[i].user_choice_index === self.questions[i].correct_choice_index) {
        score++;
      }
    }
    var percentage = score / self.questions.length;
    console.log(percentage);
    var message;
    if (percentage === 1) {
      message = 'Great job!'
    } else if (percentage >= .75) {
      message = 'You did alright.'
    } else if (percentage >= .5) {
      message = 'Better luck next time.'
    } else {
      message = 'Maybe you should try a little harder.'
    }
    $('#quiz-results-message').text(message);
    $('#quiz-results-score').html('You got <b>' + score + '/' + self.questions.length + '</b> questions correct.');
    $('#quiz-results').slideDown();
    $('#quiz button').slideUp();
  });
  question_container.bind('user-select-change', function() {
    var all_questions_answered = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.questions.length; i++) {
      if (self.questions[i].user_choice_index === null) {
        all_questions_answered = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    $('#submit-button').prop('disabled', !all_questions_answered);
  });
}

var Question = function(question_string, correct_choice, wrong_choices) {
  // Private fields for an instance of a Question object.

  this.question_string = question_string;
  this.choices = [];
  this.user_choice_index = null; // Index of the user's choice selection
  
  // Random assign the correct choice an index
  this.correct_choice_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * wrong_choices.length + 1);

  // Fill in this.choices with the choices
  var number_of_choices = wrong_choices.length + 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < number_of_choices; i++) {
    if (i === this.correct_choice_index) {
      this.choices[i] = correct_choice;
    } else {
      // Randomly pick a wrong choice to put in this index
      var wrong_choice_index = Math.floor(Math.random(0, wrong_choices.length));
      this.choices[i] = wrong_choices[wrong_choice_index];
      
      // Remove the wrong choice from the wrong choice array so that we don't pick it again
      wrong_choices.splice(wrong_choice_index, 1);
    }
  }
}

Question.prototype.render = function(container) {

  var self = this;
  

  var question_string_h2;
  if (container.children('h2').length === 0) {
    question_string_h2 = $('<h2>').appendTo(container);
  } else {
    question_string_h2 = container.children('h2').first();
  }
  question_string_h2.text(this.question_string);
  

  if (container.children('input[type=radio]').length > 0) {
    container.children('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
      var radio_button_id = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).remove();
      container.children('label[for=' + radio_button_id + ']').remove();
    });
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < this.choices.length; i++) {
    var choice_radio_button = $('<input>')
      .attr('id', 'choices-' + i)
      .attr('type', 'radio')
      .attr('name', 'choices')
      .attr('value', 'choices-' + i)
      .attr('checked', i === this.user_choice_index)
      .appendTo(container);
    

    var choice_label = $('<label>')
      .text(this.choices[i])
      .attr('for', 'choices-' + i)
      .appendTo(container);
  }
  
  
  $('input[name=choices]').change(function(index) {
    var selected_radio_button_value = $('input[name=choices]:checked').val();
    
 
    self.user_choice_index = parseInt(selected_radio_button_value.substr(selected_radio_button_value.length - 1, 1));
    
  
    container.trigger('user-select-change');
  });
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  var quiz = new Quiz('');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < all_questions.length; i++) {

    var question = new Question(all_questions[i].question_string, all_questions[i].choices.correct, all_questions[i].choices.wrong);

    quiz.add_question(question);
  }

  var quiz_container = $('#quiz');
  quiz.render(quiz_container);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Multiple Choice Quiz</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div id="quiz">
  <h1 id="quiz-name"></h1>
  <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
  <button id="next-question-button">Next</button>
  <button id="prev-question-button">Back</button>
  
  <div id="quiz-results">
    <p id="quiz-results-message"></p>
    <p id="quiz-results-score"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you do calculate the scores now. Why aren't you happy with your solution? jQuery is not relevant for the score calculation (or any other logic code) but only meant to make it easier to deal with the browser apis (DOM, window, xhr etc.)

Comment: It calculates the total score , but I want it to calculate the score for each type of questions separately. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're looking for a `group by` logic - you want to group the answers by the question type. In order to solve this:

1. Add `question_type` to `Question` (not mandatory, we can take it from the original array of question. I'll keep it for readability).
2. In order to implement the `group by` logic, we can `reduce` to **filter** the right answers and **convert** the `Question`s array into a score dictionary. The keys are the questions type, the value is the score.
   For every right answer, we either adding plus one if the category already exists or initiating as 1 if not.
   I'm using a shorter version yet does exactly the same:

```js
acc.set(curr.question_type, (acc.get(curr.question_type) || 0) + 1);
//     |-- add / update --|  |- current score if exists -| 0 if not, plus one
```

Here is the full reduce

```js
// global counter for total answers
let totalScore = 0;
const result = a.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  // if it's the right answer
  if (curr.user_choice_index === curr.correct_choice_index) {
    // add / update the entity with 1 if's the first right answer in the category so far or add 1 if it exists
    acc.set(curr.question_type, (acc.get(curr.question_type) || 0) + 1);
    totalScore++;
  }
  return acc;
}, new Map());
```

The second part is to render the results:

```js
// convert the Map back to array
const scoreText = Array.from(score.entries())
       // render each type in a different line     
      .map(([type, scoreByType]) => `<b>${type}</b>: ${scoreByType}`)
      .join('<br />');
```

Read more about

- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
- [Map.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries)
- [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Full working example:

```js
var all_questions = [{
  type:"math",
  question_string: "4 + 4",
  choices: {
    correct: "8",
    wrong: ["2", "3", "9"]
  }
}, {
  type:"math",
  question_string: "4 * 4",
  choices: {
    correct: "16",
    wrong: ["24", "13", "4"]
  }
}, {
  type:"sience",
  question_string: "What part of the body helps you move?",
  choices: {
    correct: "Muscles",
    wrong: ["Eyes", "Pancreas", "Lungs"]
  }
}, {
   type:"sience",
  question_string: 'What star shines in the day and provides light?',
  choices: {
    correct: "Sun",
    wrong: ["Moon", "Venus", "Mars"]
  }
}];
var Quiz = function(quiz_name) {
  this.quiz_name = quiz_name;
  this.questions = [];
}
Quiz.prototype.add_question = function(question) {
  var index_to_add_question = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.questions.length);
  this.questions.splice(index_to_add_question, 0, question);
}
Quiz.prototype.render = function(container) {
  var self = this;
  $('#quiz-results').hide();
  $('#quiz-name').text(this.quiz_name);
  var question_container = $('<div>').attr('id', 'question').insertAfter('#quiz-name');
  function change_question() {
    self.questions[current_question_index].render(question_container);
    $('#prev-question-button').prop('disabled', current_question_index === 0);
    $('#next-question-button').prop('disabled', current_question_index === self.questions.length - 1);
    var all_questions_answered = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.questions.length; i++) {
      if (self.questions[i].user_choice_index === null) {
        all_questions_answered = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    $('#submit-button').prop('disabled', !all_questions_answered);
  }
  var current_question_index = 0;
  change_question();
  $('#prev-question-button').click(function() {
    if (current_question_index > 0) {
      current_question_index--;
      change_question();
    }
  });
 
  $('#next-question-button').click(function() {
    if (current_question_index < self.questions.length - 1) {
      current_question_index++;
      change_question();
    }
  });
  $('#submit-button').click(function() {
    let totalScore = 0;
    const score = self.questions.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (curr.user_choice_index === curr.correct_choice_index) {
        acc.set(curr.question_type, (acc.get(curr.question_type) || 0) + 1);
        totalScore++;
      }
      return acc;
  }, new Map());
    var percentage = score / self.questions.length;
    console.log(percentage);
    var message;
    if (percentage === 1) {
      message = 'Great job!'
    } else if (percentage >= .75) {
      message = 'You did alright.'
    } else if (percentage >= .5) {
      message = 'Better luck next time.'
    } else {
      message = 'Maybe you should try a little harder.'
    }
    $('#quiz-results-message').text(message);
    const scoreText = Array.from(score.entries())
      .map(([type, scoreByType]) => `<b>${type}</b>: ${scoreByType}`)
      .join('\n');
    $('#quiz-results-score').html('You got <b>' + totalScore + '/' + self.questions.length + '</b> questions correct.\n' + scoreText);
    $('#quiz-results').slideDown();
    $('#quiz button').slideUp();
  });
  question_container.bind('user-select-change', function() {
    var all_questions_answered = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.questions.length; i++) {
      if (self.questions[i].user_choice_index === null) {
        all_questions_answered = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    $('#submit-button').prop('disabled', !all_questions_answered);
  });
}

var Question = function(question_string, correct_choice, wrong_choices, question_type) {
  // Private fields for an instance of a Question object.

  this.question_string = question_string;
  this.question_type = question_type;
  this.choices = [];
  this.user_choice_index = null; // Index of the user's choice selection
  
  // Random assign the correct choice an index
  this.correct_choice_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * wrong_choices.length + 1);

  // Fill in this.choices with the choices
  var number_of_choices = wrong_choices.length + 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < number_of_choices; i++) {
    if (i === this.correct_choice_index) {
      this.choices[i] = correct_choice;
    } else {
      // Randomly pick a wrong choice to put in this index
      var wrong_choice_index = Math.floor(Math.random(0, wrong_choices.length));
      this.choices[i] = wrong_choices[wrong_choice_index];
      
      // Remove the wrong choice from the wrong choice array so that we don't pick it again
      wrong_choices.splice(wrong_choice_index, 1);
    }
  }
}

Question.prototype.render = function(container) {

  var self = this;
  

  var question_string_h2;
  if (container.children('h2').length === 0) {
    question_string_h2 = $('<h2>').appendTo(container);
  } else {
    question_string_h2 = container.children('h2').first();
  }
  question_string_h2.text(this.question_string);
  

  if (container.children('input[type=radio]').length > 0) {
    container.children('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
      var radio_button_id = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).remove();
      container.children('label[for=' + radio_button_id + ']').remove();
    });
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < this.choices.length; i++) {
    var choice_radio_button = $('<input>')
      .attr('id', 'choices-' + i)
      .attr('type', 'radio')
      .attr('name', 'choices')
      .attr('value', 'choices-' + i)
      .attr('checked', i === this.user_choice_index)
      .appendTo(container);
    

    var choice_label = $('<label>')
      .text(this.choices[i])
      .attr('for', 'choices-' + i)
      .appendTo(container);
  }
  
  
  $('input[name=choices]').change(function(index) {
    var selected_radio_button_value = $('input[name=choices]:checked').val();
    
 
    self.user_choice_index = parseInt(selected_radio_button_value.substr(selected_radio_button_value.length - 1, 1));
    
  
    container.trigger('user-select-change');
  });
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  var quiz = new Quiz('');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < all_questions.length; i++) {

    var question = new Question(all_questions[i].question_string, all_questions[i].choices.correct, all_questions[i].choices.wrong, all_questions[i].type);

    quiz.add_question(question);
  }

  var quiz_container = $('#quiz');
  quiz.render(quiz_container);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Multiple Choice Quiz</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <div id="quiz">
    <h1 id="quiz-name"></h1>
    <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
    <button id="next-question-button">Next</button>
    <button id="prev-question-button">Back</button>

    <div id="quiz-results">
      <p id="quiz-results-message"></p>
      <p id="quiz-results-score"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My pleasure. If this answer you question, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/303669) it so it will help to other people